# Years of experience not adding correctly using jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Currently working on jquery date picker and jquery clone where with my current code my clone was working perfectly fine and my calculation working partially for example For example if i select from date as 01/04/1996 and to date as 01/01/2000 so the total years of experience is coming 4 years and 0 months. Second point is when i click add row and adding some more years for example from date as 01/01/2004 and to date as 12/01/2015 so the total should come as 15 year, 11 month but it was coming Total work experience 19 years 11month

Here is the code where i am calculating the years and months

```
 var dateStart = [];
var dateEnd = [];
$.each($('.datepicker'), function() {
  var startDateValue = $(this).val();
  var endDateValue = $(this).closest('.row').find('.endDate').val();
  if (startDateValue != "" && endDateValue != "") {
   dateStart.push(startDateValue);
   dateEnd.push(endDateValue);
   }
});

$.each($(dateStart), function(key, value) {
  var x = dateStart[key].split("/");
  var y = dateEnd[key].split("/");

  var failed = false;
  var fromdate = new Date(x[2], x[0] - 1, x[1]);
  var todate = new Date(y[2], y[0] - 1, y[1]);
  var locDiffDays = parseInt((todate.getTime() - fromdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  console.log(fromdate);
  console.log(todate);
  console.log(locDiffDays);

  if (locDiffDays < 0) {
    alert("To date " + dateEnd[key] + " should be greater then from date " + dateStart[key]);
    console.log("invalid from and to dates");
    failed = true;
    return false;
  }

  if (dateStart[key - 1]) {
    var x1 = dateStart[key - 1].split("/");
    var y1 = dateEnd[key - 1].split("/");

    var fromdate1 = new Date(x1[2], x1[0] - 1, x1[1]);
    var todate1 = new Date(y1[2], y1[0] - 1, y1[1]);
    var locDiffDays1 = parseInt((todate1.getTime() - fromdate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    console.log(x1);
    console.log(y1);
    console.log(fromdate1);
    console.log(todate1);
    console.log(locDiffDays1);

    var locDiffDays2 = parseInt((fromdate.getTime() - fromdate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var locDiffDays3 = parseInt((todate.getTime() - todate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var locDiffDays4 = parseInt((fromdate.getTime() - todate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    console.log("locDiffDays2: " + locDiffDays2);
    if (locDiffDays2 < 0) {
      alert("From date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous from date " + dateStart[key - 1]);
      console.log("invalid from dates");
      failed = true;
      return false;
    }

    if (locDiffDays3 < 0) {
      alert("To date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous To date " + dateStart[key - 1]);
      console.log("invalid from dates");
      failed = true;
      return false;
    }

    if (locDiffDays4 < 0) {
      alert("From date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous To date " + dateEnd[key - 1]);
      console.log("invalid from dates");
      failed = true;
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (key == dateStart.length - 1 && !failed) {
    var firstDate = dateStart[0].split('/');
    firstDate = new Date(firstDate[2], firstDate[0] - 1, firstDate[1]);
    var lastDate = dateEnd[dateEnd.length - 1].split('/');
    lastDate = new Date(lastDate[2], lastDate[0] - 1, lastDate[1]);
    console.log(lastDate);
    console.log(firstDate);
    //var diffYears = (lastDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    var diffMonths = monthDiff(firstDate, lastDate);
    //diffYears = parseInt(''+diffYears);

    var diffYears = diffMonths / 12;
    diffYears = parseInt('' + diffYears);

    diffMonths = diffMonths - (diffYears * 12)

    $("#txt_expy>span").text(diffYears);
    $("#txt_expm>span").text(diffMonths);
  }
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bqgjro6d/48/)

Comment: Dont clone html for datetime picker. you need to rebind datetimepicker every tine to make it fully working.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi actually this was just was part of my entire code actully it require clone for adding years of exp

Comment: As per calculation it dosn't consider year value to add.It dosn't calculate from 01/01/2004 but from 01/01/2000 so extra 4 yrs added to 15+4 = 19.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi yes that was the problem not only for this years this was calculating perfectly when the coninous year was there but if i put some random years this was not working  i was seriously  confused how to fix

Comment: Currently i am not getting add experience button on fiddle you given.

Comment: you have to click add row button then add the years

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97372/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-mahadevan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the above question I have created row Index based on the row index if i click new row new index will be generated based on that i am adding the years.

Here is the code

```
function updateDiff(ri) {
        //console.log("row index ", ri);
      var dateStart = [];
      var dateEnd = [];

      $.each($('.datepicker'), function() {
        var startDateValue = $(this).val();
        var endDateValue = $(this).closest('.row').find('.endDate').val();
        if (startDateValue != "" && endDateValue != "") {
          dateStart.push(startDateValue);
          dateEnd.push(endDateValue);
        }
      });

      $.each($(dateStart), function(key, value) {
        console.log("Key: " +  key);
        var x = dateStart[key].split("/");
        var y = dateEnd[key].split("/");

        var failed = false;
        var fromdate = new Date(x[2], x[0] - 1, x[1]);
        var todate = new Date(y[2], y[0] - 1, y[1]);
        var locDiffDays = parseInt((todate.getTime() - fromdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if (locDiffDays < 0) {
          alert("To date " + dateEnd[key] + " should be greater then from date " + dateStart[key]);
          console.log("invalid from and to dates");
          failed = true;
          return false;
        }

        if (dateStart[key - 1]) {
          var x1 = dateStart[key - 1].split("/");
          var y1 = dateEnd[key - 1].split("/");

          var fromdate1 = new Date(x1[2], x1[0] - 1, x1[1]);
          var todate1 = new Date(y1[2], y1[0] - 1, y1[1]);
          var locDiffDays1 = parseInt((todate1.getTime() - fromdate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

          var locDiffDays2 = parseInt((fromdate.getTime() - fromdate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          var locDiffDays3 = parseInt((todate.getTime() - todate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          var locDiffDays4 = parseInt((fromdate.getTime() - todate1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

          console.log("locDiffDays2: " + locDiffDays2);
          if (locDiffDays2 < 0) {
            alert("From date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous from date " + dateStart[key - 1]);
            console.log("invalid from dates");
            failed = true;
            return false;
          }

          if (locDiffDays3 < 0) {
            alert("To date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous To date " + dateStart[key - 1]);
            console.log("invalid from dates");
            failed = true;
            return false;
          }

          if (locDiffDays4 < 0) {
            alert("From date " + dateStart[key] + " should be greater than previous To date " + dateEnd[key - 1]);
            console.log("invalid from dates");
            failed = true;
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (key == dateStart.length - 1 && !failed) {
          var firstDate = $("#expy-"+ri+" .startDate").val().split('/'); //dateStart[ri+ri+1].split('/');
          var lastDate = $("#expy-"+ri+" .endDate").val().split('/'); //dateEnd[ri+ri+2].split('/');
          //console.log("dateStart["+(ri-1)+"]: ", dateStart[ri-1]);
          //console.log("dateStart["+ri+"]: ", dateStart[ri]);
          if( (firstDate!="") && (lastDate!="") && (!dateRegex.test(firstDate)) && (!dateRegex.test(lastDate)) ) {
            firstDate = new Date(firstDate[2], firstDate[0] - 1, firstDate[1]);

              lastDate = new Date(lastDate[2], lastDate[0] - 1, lastDate[1]);


              diffMonths1 = monthDiff(firstDate, lastDate);
              diffYears1 = diffMonths1 / 12;

              diffYears += parseInt('' + diffYears1);            
              diffMonths += diffMonths1 - (diffYears1 * 12)

              document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML = diffYears;
              document.getElementById("txt_expm").innerHTML = diffMonths;

          }

        }

      });


    }
```